# jQuery combine input checkbox, dates and text values into one value string based on name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I am using the following php & jquery to process a simple product form within WordPress Admin which works fine for the input checkboxes. However, I am trying to combine a mix of both checkboxes AND text input fields as well as a date field into the one servicelist[] value.

```
let values = [];
        $("input[name='servicelist[]']:checked").each(function() {
             values.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Normally I would use something like servicestartdate: $("#servicestartdate").val(), however I need this to pull through with the servicelist[] value as the results will loop for however many products are selected. The values are then imploded in the email template.

My attempts are not working as I'm not experienced with jQuery and not sure how I can include text inputs with the code below. I have tried removing the :checked as well as replacing with :val yet this breaks the jQuery. I have also tried creating an additional value which also breaks the code.

Hope this makes sense. Any suggestions would be very helpful! Thanks.

Here is the full php, jquery and email code...

**Form PHP & JQUERY:** (Note: Make sure your path to email.php is correct)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function sendSupplierForm() {
        
        let values = [];
        $("input[name='servicelist[]']:checked").each(function() {
             values.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        var data = {
            ordernumber: $("#ordernumber").val(),
            servicelist: values
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        dataType:'text',
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#EmailStatus").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
}
</script>

<div id="SupplierForm">
    <div id="EmailStatus"></div>
    <label><input type="text" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber" value="1234567890">ID</label><br>
    <label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist1" value="Service1">Service1</label><br>
    <label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist2" value="Service2">Service2</label><br>
    <label><input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist3" value="Service3">Service3</label><br>

    <label>Date: <input type="date" name="servicelist[]" id="servicestartdate"></label>
    <label>Price: <input type="text" name="servicelist[]" id="supplierpriceperlift" value="£16.75"></label>

    <div name="submit" class="btnAction" onClick="sendSupplierForm();">Send</div>
</div>
```

**email.php** (Note: Make sure you change the email addresses for it to work)

```
<?php
$mailto = "info@******.com";
$subject = "Test";
$headers = "From: info@******.com\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

$seperate = implode("<br>",$_POST['servicelist']);

$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Supplier Form Details</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Original Order Number: " . $_POST['ordernumber'] . "</p>
  <p>Service List: <br>" . $seperate . "</p>
</body>
</html>
";

$result1 = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($result1) {
print "<p class='success'>SUCCESS!!! The details have been sent.</p>";
} else {
print "<p class='Error'>ERROR... Sorry there is a problem sending the details.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an email problem? I doubt that all technologies are involved here

Comment: You should start by checking whether the data is handled in the browser as expected - does that AJAX request sent what it **should** send? If yes, this is probably not a JS problem. If not, this is most likely not a PHP problem

Comment: Thanks Nico. I should have made my question clearer. This is a jQuery problem of combining checkboxes AND input values into one. Rakesh has provided a good answer below which shows them combined.

Comment: Then please feel free to remove all irrelevant parts to make it more focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let values = [];
$("input[name='servicelist[]']:checked, #servicestartdate, #servicestartdate").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Here I am basically selecting elements with multiple selectors..

1. input[name='servicelist[]']:checked
2. #servicestartdate
3. #servicestartdate

and jQuery will return the full collection, which then you can iterate.

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. This is what I was looking for. I could not understand how to combine  mix of checkboxes and inputs in the jQuery. Is there also a way to include the labels for each input box?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, sorry, was in rush.. I have edited my answer as suggested..

Comment: Yes @DavidSmith, you defintely can, but it would be easier if you can move the checkboxes out of the labels.. somethin like <label for="dd"><input type="checkbox"> but remember for label, you won't have val(), instead you will be using text()